# How to write down an explicit equation of given degree yielding a smooth hypersurface in a projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, projective-varieties

Let F be a field of positive characteristic $p$ and let $d,n$ be two positive integers.
Can we explicitly write down an equation defining a *smooth* hypersurface $X_d⊂\mathbb P^n_F$ of degree d ?
This is easy if $p$ does not divide $d$: the Fermat equation $∑x^d_i=0$ will do.
But what if $p$ *does* divide $d$ ?

Comment: The table in section 3 of Poonen's http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/projaut.pdf does this.

Comment: (Katz also faced this problem in https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nmk/baby16.pdf —- see Section 6.)

Comment: @SashaP : thank you for your comment

Comment: In the case $p\vert d$ the equation mentioned by @alpoge is due to Ofer Gabber and is $x_0^d+\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}x_ix_{i+1}^{d-1}=0$. 
This is much better than my answer, which I'm thus deleting.

Comment: @alpoge Ofer Gaber's example in your reference is much better than mine. Could you please explain in an answer, (which can then be upvoted) , since I have deleted my own answer .

Comment: I dunno I kinda like your examples better :p. Why delete them? You could just add Gabber’s to your answer in an edit! I only meant to point out that this problem came up in Katz’s context!

Comment: @alpoge: You are very  kind but I think my examples were actually flawed. You really saved my day and I heartily  congratulate you for finding such an advanced  and pertinent reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Np!! I admit I didn’t check smoothness of your examples :p —- I’m glad the link helped!